# Password checker - check for 2 identical characters adjacent with one another

Tags: regex, vb.net, passwords

I'm doing a program that will determine the strength of a password in vb.net

The characteristics of a "STRONG" password is the following:

1) Must have at least 8 characters long

2) Must be a combination of Letters, Numbers, and Symbols

3) Must have at least 2 capital letters and

4) Must not have 2 identical characters adjacent with one another.

Example: 
b@LLp3n = WEAK

P@ssw0rd = WEAK

k3Yb0Ard! = Strong

C0MPUT3R = WEAK

S+@Rcr4ft = STRONG

PROBLEM:
My concern is correct code for checking the 2 identical characters that are adjacent with one another.

Here is the Code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    Dim password As String = txtInput.Text
    Dim numUpper As Integer = 2
    Dim passLength As Integer = 8
    Dim specialLength As Integer = 1


    Dim upper As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[A-Z]")
    Dim specialChar As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")


    If password.Length < passLength Then
        MessageBox.Show("The Password Is Weak-")
    ElseIf upper.Matches(password).Count < numUpper Then
        MessageBox.Show("The Password Is Weak!")
    ElseIf specialChar.Matches(password).Count < specialLength Then
        MessageBox.Show("The Password Is Weak+")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The Password Is Strong")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

I hope someone can help me to figure this out.

Comment: `If Regex.IsMatch(password,"(.)\1")`....

Comment: Thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew :)

Comment: See my answer, I added some more details.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. It really works for me and I appreciate the reference for RegEx. I will use it for upcoming projects related to password verification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add another `If` condition to your method:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(password,"(.)\1") Then
    MessageBox.Show("There are identical consecutive chars!")
End If
```

The `(.)\1` pattern will match and capture any char but a newline (with `(.)`)  and the `\1` backreference to Group 1 value will match the same char captured in Group 1. See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%29%5c1&i=Brood).

You may further enhance this. Say, you allow two identical consecutive chars, but you do not want to allow 3 identical char streaks. Then use `(.)\1{2}` that will require 2 occurrences of the same char captured in Group 1.

Comment: Thank you so much @Wiktor

I get it now. And I really appreciate the reference for regex reference. I will use it soon.